# onclick JS event on a image map?

Tags: javascript, image

I have been searching for hours for an answer here at stackoverflow and in the web. However all the answers I tried didn't work for me.

Basically, I would like to put an onclick event on an image map. the event is a java script function. When the user click on an area element it will download the text on the editor as a word file.

To illustrate what I'm trying to explain, here is the https://jsfiddle.net/00bk1zad/ with the code I made. I don't know what should I edit to make it working.

Thank you!

The code:

```js
function txtdownload() {
  console.log('called')
  var textToSave = document.getElementById("editor").value;
  var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob([textToSave], {
    type: "application/msword"
  });
  var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
  var fileNameToSaveAs = "YouKtub.doc";
  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
  downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
  downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
  downloadLink.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
}
```

```html
<div align=center>
  <textarea id="editor" wrap="PHYSICAL" name="q" rows="9"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eYKuFc/img.jpg" usemap="#map1Map" border=0>
</div>
<map name=map1Map> <area coords="268,46,47,113" href="#" onclick="txtdownload()"> </map>
```

Comment: What is this `destroyClickedElement`??

Comment: Check your console, you have an error when clicking your button.

Comment: Your event is actually called, however, it crashes executing this line `downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;`.  What is this `destroyClickedElement?`

Comment: Please use the jsfiddle link provided. When I click the button nothing happen. that's the issue I'm trying to fix.

Comment: I really have no idea what is **destroyClickedElement**. I just copied the whole java script code from another website and past it on my HTML page. hoping it will work but it didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed `downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;` and added `document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);` at the end. So when you press button and download file, the hidden link is destroyed. (Works in Chrome)

**UPDATE:** (now works in Firefox locally or on JSFiddle - stackoverflow codesnippet still doesn't work) In area tag I removed `onclick="txtdownload()"` and changed `href="#"` to `href="javascript:txtdownload()"`. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/00bk1zad/2/

For future, you can use FileSaver.js. Check this link with examples: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

```js
function txtdownload() {
 var textToSave = document.getElementById("editor").value;
  var textToSaveAsBlob = new Blob(
    [textToSave],
    {type:"application/msword"});
  var textToSaveAsURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(textToSaveAsBlob);
  var fileNameToSaveAs = "YouKtub.doc";
  var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
  downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
  downloadLink.href = textToSaveAsURL;
  downloadLink.style.display = "none";
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
  document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
 }
```

```html
<div align=center>
  <textarea id="editor" wrap="PHYSICAL" name="q" rows="9"></textarea>
</div>

<div>
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/eYKuFc/img.jpg" usemap="#map1Map" border=0>
</div>

<map name=map1Map>
  <area coords="268,46,47,113" href="javascript:txtdownload()">
</map>
```

Comment: When I click the button, nothing happen.. downloading doesn't start.

Comment: I updated the answer. Works with Firefox on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/00bk1zad/2/

Comment: Your welcome! This cross-browser support is mysterious thing :-)